# "One of each" vs "one of each one"

Tags: grammar

I understand that "one" in "one of each one" is redundant, but is "each one" incorrect here as in grammatically incorrect, or just redundant, because although it doesn't sound good, I am tempted to say that it's not ungrammatical. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that "one of each one" is ungrammatical, but it sounds awkward, unless there is context that clarifies it. Without context or an intended meaning, this is hard to respond to.

"Each one" is very commonly used:

> The school asked the students for addresses, and got a response from each one.

But "one of each one" is unusual, unless it is intended to indicate a sub selection:

> There were five groups of people, and we selected one of each one as a representative

Even there it is probably not the most natural expression.